# Are projections and perpendiculars linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Is there a proof or disproof for this statement?

If **P** is a plane in $\mathbb R ^3 $ then { $proj_\mathbf{p}\mathbf{v}$, $perp_\mathbf{p}\mathbf{v}$ } is linearly independent for any **v** in  $\mathbb R ^3 $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are only linearly independent if both are non-zero: For a plane $P\subseteq \mathbb R^3$ choose an orthonormal basis $p_1,p_2$ of $P$ and let complete to an orthonormal basis $p_1,p_2,p_3$ of $\mathbb R^3$. Then
$$
{\rm proj}\colon \mathbb R^3\longrightarrow \mathbb R^3, v\longmapsto \sum_{i=1}^3\langle v,p_i\rangle\cdot p_i
$$
is a projection (i. e. ${\rm proj}\circ {\rm proj} = {\rm proj}$) with image $P$ and kernel ${\rm span}(p_3)$.

Now, for $v\in \mathbb R^3$ such that ${\rm proj}(v)\neq 0$ and $v':= {\rm perp}_Pv\in {\rm span}(p_3)\setminus\{0\}$ we have $v' \in \ker({\rm proj})$. Hence, if $0 = \lambda\cdot {\rm proj}(v) + \mu\cdot v'$, then
$$
0 = {\rm proj}(\lambda\cdot {\rm proj}(v) + \mu\cdot v') = \lambda\cdot {\rm proj}({\rm proj}(v)) + \mu\cdot {\rm proj}(v') = \lambda\cdot {\rm proj}(v),
$$
i. e. $\lambda = 0$. This also implies $\mu=0$ which proves the claim.

Comment: Just two small details: (1) You want to assume that $v' \neq 0$. (2) Strictly speaking $P$  isn’t assumed to be a plane through the origin, although we can do this by translating the plane if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Apparently I had a slightly different idea then the question asker about what the unspecified projections $\operatorname{proj}_P$ and $\operatorname{perp}_P$ are meant to be, so this post probably does not answer the question in the way the asker intended it. In the case that the plane $P$ goes through the origin and that the line $L$, which is orthogonal to $P$ and needed to define $\operatorname{proj}_P$ and $\operatorname{perp}_P$, although goes through the origin, both interpretations of the question coincide. It is in particular shown that the statement does not necessarily hold.

---

We will use the following:

> ***Lemma:*** Let $v_1, \dotsc, v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be non-zero and pairwise orthogonal vectors, i.e. $v_i \cdot v_j = 0$ if $1 \leq i \neq j \leq k$ and $\|v_i\| > 0$ for every $1 \leq i \leq k$. Then $(v_1, \dotsc, v_k)$ is linearly independent.
>
> ***Proof:*** Let $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_k \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 = \sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j v_j$. Then for every $1 \leq i \leq k$ we get
>   $$
>  0
>  = v_i \cdot 0
>  = v_i \cdot \sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j v_j
>  = \sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j v_i \cdot v_j
>  = \lambda_j \|v_j\|^2,
> $$
>   and because $\|v_j\|^2 > 0$ it follows that $\lambda_j = 0$.

---

For $\operatorname{proj}_P$ and $\operatorname{perp}_P$ to make sense we first need to fix a line $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is orthogonal to $P$. Then let $\operatorname{proj}^L_P$ be the projection onto $P$ along $L$ and $\operatorname{perp}_P^L$ the projection onto $L$ along $P$.

More explicitely: Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be the unique point at which $L$ and $P$ intersect. Let $u_1, u_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ be orthonormal vectors (i.e. $u_1 \cdot u_2 = 0$ and $\|u_1\| = \|u_2\| = 1$) such that
$$
 P
 = a + \mathbb{R} u_1 + \mathbb{R} u_2
 = \{ a + \lambda u_1 + \mu u_2 \mid \lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}\}.
$$
Let $u_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a normed vector (i.e. $\|u_3\| = 1$) with
$$
 L
 = a + \mathbb{R} u_3
 = \{a + \lambda u_3 \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}.
$$
Then $\operatorname{proj}^L_P$ and $\operatorname{perp}^L_P$ are given by
$$
 \operatorname{proj}^L_P v
 = (u_1 \cdot (v-a)) u_1 + (u_2 \cdot (v-a)) u_2
$$
and
$$
 \operatorname{perp}^L_P v
 = (u_3 \cdot (v-a)) u_3.
$$

So $a + \operatorname{proj}^L_P v \in P$ and $a + \operatorname{perp}^L_P v \in P$

(In the special case that $a = 0$, that is if $P$ is a plane through the origin and $L$ is line through the origin which is orthogonal to $P$, both these maps are linear.)

---

Notice that $(u_1, u_2, u_3)$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$: Because $L$ and $P$ are orthogonal we find that $u_1 \cdot u_2 = u_1 \cdot u_3 = 0$ (here we use a geometric argument to skip some otherwise lengthy calculations), and because $u_2$ and $u_3$ are also orthogonal to each other we find that $u_1, u_2, u_3$ are non-zero and pairwise orthogonal vectors. By the lemma above we find that $(u_1, u_2, u_3)$ is linearly independent. Because $\dim \mathbb{R}^3 = 3$ it follows that it is already a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and because the $u_i$ are pairwise orthogonal with $\|u_i\| = 1$ for every $1 \leq i \leq 3$ it is already an orthonormal basis.

---

In particular we have $\operatorname{proj}^L_P v = 0$ if and only if $u_1 \cdot (v-a) = u_2 \cdot (v-a) = 0$, which is now equivalent to $v-a \in \mathbb{R} u_3$, which is the same as $v \in a + \mathbb{R} u_3 = L$.

In the same way we have $\operatorname{perp}^L_P v = 0$ if and only if $u_3 \cdot (v-a) = 0$, which is equivalent to $v-a \in \mathbb{R} u_1 + \mathbb{R} u_2$ and thus equivalent to $v \in a + \mathbb{R} u_1 + \mathbb{R} u_2 = P$.

We also find that for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ the two vectors $\operatorname{proj}^L_P v = \lambda_1 u_1 + \lambda_2 u_2$ and $\operatorname{perp}^L_P v = \mu u_3$ are orthogonal because
$$
 (\lambda_1 u_1 + \lambda_2 u_2) \cdot (\mu u_3)
 = \lambda_1 \mu u_1 \cdot u_3 + \lambda_2 \mu u_2 \cdot u_3
 = 0.
$$

---

If $v \in P$ then $\operatorname{proj}^L_P v = 0$, so your statement does not hold for $v \in P$. Similarly it doesn’t works if $v \in L$ because then $\operatorname{perp}^L_P v = 0$.

If on the other hand both $v_P := \operatorname{proj}^L_P v$ and $v_L := \operatorname{perp}^L_P v$ are non-zero then we also know that $v_P$ and $v_L$ are orthogonal, so by the above lemma $(v_P, v_L)$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Could you explain why $\operatorname{proj}_Pv$ and $\operatorname{perp}_Pv$ (both non-zero) are perpendicular when the plane does not go through the origin?

Comment: The underlying arguments are the same; I added some more details.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. But one thing that is confusing is, that you didn't define $\operatorname{proj}_Pv$ to lie on the plane $P$ and in fact $v\neq \operatorname{proj}^L_Pv + \operatorname{perp}^L_Pv$ if $a\neq 0$. Is this the standard way to define $\operatorname{proj}_P^L$; could you give a reference?

Comment: Apperently we have a different ideas about what the projections are supposed to be; in a case like this it would be _very_ helpful if you provided _your definition_ of the projections in your question, and would clarify your exact question. If we take $P$ and $L$ such that $a = 0$ both of our definitions should coincide (as far as I can tell), and this posts still shows that the statement does not always hold. If this answers your question depends on whether you fix the plane $P$ (and $L$, which you did not mention) for the question or not.

Comment: In the case that $P$ does not go through the origin I think this question is very hard to answer, if even possible, in all its generality. Because then we have to look at every translated version of the plane, and vector space properties like linear independence behave very poorly under such non-linear (in the sense of linear algebra) operations.